# Show MPAndroidChart Linechart X and Y axis value at any point

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have implemented a line chart using mpandroidchart library. I have added a custom markerview to show the data on a label when chart is clicked. But it shows data only on specific data point which I have mentioned on dataset. I want to show x and y axis value at any pixel point when chart is clicked.

[image]